# Does a Try/Except block create a stack of its own?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def f(n):
    if n>0:
        print(1/n)
    else:
        raise Exception
try:
    f(0)
except Exception:
    print("Error!")
```

When Exception is raised inside f(n), does the interpreter return to the try/except block (which implies the try/except has its own block), or is that error being raised and handled immediately (which implies the opposite) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actualy it raises **from the f(n) function** up until it finds a **try/catch** handler **or** the end of the **program stack**. In this last case, the program will stop and raise the error ti the user (through the console).

this will raise the exception up to the user:

```
def f(n):
    raise Exception

f(5)
```

But if you add a try/catch in between, the exception will be handle by the except block:

```
def f(n):
    raise Exception

try:
    f(5)
except:
    print('Error handled')
```

Comment: Good explanation, bad use of try/except (using a blank except statement is bad practice)

Comment: Yes true, for the example I used a simple print display to show what can append if you handle an Exception but as @Two-BitAlchemist said,if you want to handle such error **you have to** perform another code but never leave the except bloc blanck (with no real handle)

Answer (score 2):

In your case, I think this is more pythonic:

```
def f(n):
    try:
        print(1/n)
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print ("can't divide by zero")
```

You never want to raise a blanket exception because you loose the chance to learn what went wrong